# Error Message: The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address

Tags: .net, vb.net, email, visual-studio-2012

The function `ValidateEmail()` returns true but `trimiteEmail()` throws an error:

`The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.`

This is the send function

```
Public Function trimiteEmail(destinatar As String) As Boolean

    Dim upString As String = "<div>xxx</div>"
    Dim downString As String = "<div>xxx</div>"

    If Not ValidateEmail(destinatar) = True Then
        MsgBox(destinatar & " nu este un mail valid")
        Return False
    End If

    Try
        Dim mail As New MailMessage
        mail.From = New MailAddress("gabriel@ftnet.ro")
        mail.To.Add(New MailAddress(destinatar))
        mail.Subject = Baza.subiect.Text
        mail.Body = upString & Baza.sourceCode.Text & downString
        mail.IsBodyHtml = True


        Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("mail.ftnet.ro")
        smtp.Port = 587
        smtp.EnableSsl = False

        Dim credentials As New NetworkCredential("gabriel@ftnet.ro", "******")

        smtp.Credentials = credentials
        smtp.Host = "mail.ftnet.ro"


        smtp.Send(mail)
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return False
    End Try


End Function
```

This is the reference timer.

```
Public Sub TimerSend()

        If InternetRetea.verificareAdresa("http://www.fire.ro/") = False Then
            Baza.TimerSend.Stop()
            initTimeCheck()
        Else

            Dim count As Integer = Baza.listaEmail.Rows.Count

            If trimiteEmail(Baza.listaEmail.Rows(sCount).Cells("Email").Value.ToString) = True Then
                Baza.status.Text = sCount + 1 & "/" & count & " Success To: " & Baza.listaEmail.Rows(sCount).Cells("Email").Value
                My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(Baza.listaNews.SelectedItem & ".txt", Baza.listaEmail.Rows(sCount).Cells("Email").Value & " SEND " & sCount & vbCrLf, True)
            Else
                Baza.status.Text = sCount + 1 & "/" & count & " Failed To: " & Baza.listaEmail.Rows(sCount).Cells("Email").Value
                My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(Baza.listaNews.SelectedItem & ".txt", Baza.listaEmail.Rows(sCount).Cells("Email").Value & " ERROR " & sCount & vbCrLf, True)
            End If

            sCount = sCount + 1

            If count = sCount Then
                Baza.status.Text = "Process completed"
                Baza.TimerSend.Stop()
                sCount = 0
            End If

        End If

    End Sub
```

This is the exception

```
System.FormatException was unhandled
  Message=The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Mime.MailBnfHelper.ReadMailAddress(String data, Int32& offset, String& displayName)
       at System.Net.Mail.MailAddress.ParseValue(String address)
       at System.Net.Mail.MailAddress..ctor(String address, String displayName, Encoding displayNameEncoding)
       at Fire_Newsletter.Setari.trimiteEmail(String destinatar) in D:\Proiecte\Basic\Fire Newsletter\Fire Newsletter\Setari.vb:line 214
       at Fire_Newsletter.Setari.TimerSend() in D:\Proiecte\Basic\Fire Newsletter\Fire Newsletter\Setari.vb:line 288
       at Fire_Newsletter.Setari._Lambda$__2(Object a0, EventArgs a1) in D:\Proiecte\Basic\Fire Newsletter\Fire Newsletter\Setari.vb:line 274
       at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
```

Thank you

Comment: Well.. what inputs are you using (for `destinatar` in particular)? are the email addresses likely-looking email addresses?

Comment: Yes is datagridview with email adresses --> trimiteEmail(Baza.listaEmail.Rows(sCount).Cells("Email").Value.ToString       listaEmail contains email adresess

Comment: that really doesn't help us to identify the problem. Without an example of that that *evaluates to* (with dummy email addresses, obviously), how are we expected to help? Usually, such errors occur because what you *expected* is different to reality. So: find out what `Baza.listaEmail.Rows(sCount).Cells("Email").Value.ToString` **evaluates to**.

Comment: Above we display the source code. At this address is the screenshots of the error. [http://www.ftnet.ro/err.jpg ] The problem is that when I want to send a newsletter I get error . For this function trimiteEmail(destinatar) i using Timer. 
Timer takes each row of the DataGridView at an interval of 7 seconds and send an email to the email address corresponding row. Sorry for my english

Comment: And again: a screenshot does **not** tell us what the string actually evaluated to. It tells us about your *expectation*, but not about reality. Seriously, just evaluate `Baza.listaEmail.Rows(sCount).Cells("Email").Value.ToString` and find out what that is. For all you know it might be something like `Some.Namespace.GridCell`. So again, and I cannot emphasize this enough: **find out what the string is**. You can probably just put a breakpoint on the first line of `trimiteEmail` and just hover over `destinatar`

Comment: Marc: i used this function to verify email adress -->     Function IsValidEmailFormat(ByVal s As String) As Boolean
        Try
            Dim a As New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(s)
        Catch
            Return False
        End Try
        Return True
    End Function   ' This function return False and the address is gabriel@ftnet.ro, Any idea why?

Comment: Does `trimiteEmail("gabriel@ftnet.ro")` work? If yes, then the problem is in what you are passing to the method, so you need to find that out and compare.

Comment: Yes: trimiteEmail("gabriel@ftnet.ro") Work !

Comment: With regEx function return valid address, but in mail.To.Add(New MailAddress() is not correct !

Comment: since you indicate neither the actual value of `destinatar`, nor the regex that you are using, I can make no comment whatsoever on that

Answer (score 0):

> Yes: trimiteEmail("gabriel@ftnet.ro") Work !

Then the problem is in the expression:

```
Baza.listaEmail.Rows(sCount).Cells("Email").Value.ToString
```

You need to find out what this is evaluating to, since it clearly isn't what you are expecting. This could simply be because it has padding (spaces before and/or after the word), but it could be because `.Value` is some type that doesn't provide the `ToString` implementation you are expecting. The *default* `ToString` implementation is simply: the full type name, so it could be that `.Value.ToString` is `Some.Namespace.SomeType`. You need to **find out what that is evaluating to**, and fix it. The simplest approach, as already mentioned, is probably to put a breakpoint in `trimiteEmail`, hit play, and when it pauses simply inspect the value of `destinatar`. If it looks like the email address, check for padding; it might be that adding `destinar = destinar.Trim` fixes it. If it looks nothing like an email address, then you need to investigate the *correct* way of getting a cell value from your grid control.